# Is It possible to build Tfs_Warehouse locally using TFS Web Access

Tags: tfs, data-warehouse

I am a part of the team where the TFS 2012 is being used. I am not sure I can get SQL access to the TFS Warehouse. So like to know if it is possible to reconstruct the TFS Warehouse or Analysis service on my local machine. Is there any web services exposed via TFS 2012? Does it need any special permission.

I looking for TFS Analysis database as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244699%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

After lot of research found that it is not possible. The main missing information is the relationship between the items. like User story to tasks relationship. Without this we can not do much.